# Is there any alternative to the EM algorithm?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, computational-statistics, expectation-maximization

I am working on biomedical signal analysis and the most used method for parameters estimation is the EM algorithm.

My question is : what are the most powerful alternatives to this algorithm?

Comment: What exactly are you using EM for? This algorithm is has really many uses, so you have to be more precise.

Comment: @Tim I am using it for estimating the parameters of different normally distributed classes.

Comment: @Tim It is a gaussian mixture model and the data is brain MRI scans.

Comment: OK, now it is more clear. As far as I know EM is most commonly used in this area, but Bayesian estimation is also possible - have you considered it?

Comment: @Tim yes, i know that it is possible to use EM with the MAP criterion (which is a kind of Bayesian reasoning). But i am looking for an alternative.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to provide additional details. Why EM is not good for you? As far as I know EM is a state-of-art in this area, so maybe say why it is not satisfactory?

Comment: @Tim I am not saying that it is not satisfactory, i am just looking for something different to try.

Comment: Then you could probably try Bayesian MCMC, but others may provide a more detailed answer. BTW, consider editing your question to add all those deatils that came out in our discussion so others know better what are you looking for.